# Burninate [sku]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku) has 25 questions, 0 followers and the following description

> SKU stands for Stock Keeping Unit, and is a product or service identification code that helps track the item for inventory. This tag relates to Questions regarding identification systems usually used to track inventory.

A lot of these questions seem to have the tags [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento), etc.

SKU's themselves are not related to programming or computer science. I don't think adding [sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku) add's anything to a question that isn't covered by adding a tag with the software name being used.

Comment: -1 for not having a pun in the title.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Would skewer [tag:sku] be more appropriate?

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Should we un[sku]w this tag?

Comment: @JustinWood sure

Comment: With this few questions it would have been OK just to edit them all.